# Interpret and Display NC code (G-Code) and display on a form

Tags: g-code, twincat-hmi, lasercutting

I am developing an HMI application using C# and VS 2017 for a laser cutting machine and I have a form on which I would like to load the NC code of the part to be cut by the laser. Once the NC code is loaded, I want the part to be displayed on a panel in the form. But i cannot find any libraries or packages that can be used for this task.

I tried a number of 3rd party dll's but of not much success mainly because of a lot of limitations in terms of functionalities.